# Reference Request: Peak points of $A(K)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Given $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ one defines $A(K)$ to be the uniform algebra of functions that are continuous on $K$ and holomorphic on the interior of $K$. 
If $z \in K$ is such that there is some $f \in A(K)$ with $||f||:= \max\{|f(\xi)|:\xi\in K\}$=$|f(z)|$ and $|f(\xi)|<||f||$ for every $\xi \in K \setminus \{z\}$, then $z$ is called a *peak point* for $A(K)$.
In his article "On the peak points" Arthur Danielyan writes that it is well known that if $K$ has connected complement, then every boundary point of $K$ is a peak point and vice versa.
Does anyone know a some book which explicitly mentions this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about a google search for ["peak set" + "connected component" + "boundary"](https://www.google.com/search?q=+%22peak+set%22+%22connected+complement%22+%22boundary%22&filter=0)? For a book, possibly John Garnett's 1972 book [**Analytic Capacity and Measure**](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0060912), but I don't have a copy (or paywall access) to check for sure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your comment. The google search did not yield anything usefull (which, I think, is no surprise) but your book recommendation helped.